# после обновления Kubuntu 11.04 -> 11.10 не загружается система

Tags: kubuntu

Добрый день, помогите, пожалуйста, с такой проблемой: после того как обновил систему на ноуте, система грузится до того момента пока не появляется окно авторизации, ввожу парольлогин и всё... дальше ничего не происходит, снова появляется это окно, а сама система не грузится. Причём клава и тачпад не работают ноутовские, почему-то работают только usb-клава и мыш. В чём может быть проблема? И как её исправить?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Нужны логи /var/log/Xorg.0.log и желательно вывод dmesg

Comment: вот ссылка на логи Xorg.0.log http://dumpz.org/170056/dmesg - а это как сделать?

Comment: dmesg лежит тут - /var/log/dmesg.Либо вываливается на экран при вводе в консоле dmesg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зайди в защищенный режим при загрузке, создай нового пользователя.перезагрузись и в графическом режиме попробуй зайти под новым именем, может помочь, хотя не всегдаИли, если есть возможность при входе поменять графическую среду с КДЕ на какой либо легкий Х типа блекбокса, попробуй зайти с него